# mysql result in one json object

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

this is my code:

```
$query = "select ((recipients.maennlichDeutsch+recipients.maennlichAuslaender+recipients.weiblichDeutsch+recipients.weiblichAuslaender)/inhab.Einwohner) as Sozialhilfeempfaenger from recipients left join education on recipients.Bundesland = education.FK_Land and recipients.Jahr = education.FK_Jahr left join inhab on recipients.Bundesland = inhab.FK_land and recipients.Jahr = inhab.FK_Jahr where recipients.Bundesland in ('Thueringen') and education.Abschluss in ('Hauptschulabschluss')";
$result=mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');
$data = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

and this is the json result i get :

```
[    
    {
        "Sozialhilfeempfaenger": "0.0208"
    },    
    {
        "Sozialhilfeempfaenger": "0.0202"
    },    
    {
        "Sozialhilfeempfaenger": "0.0198"
    },    
    {
        "Sozialhilfeempfaenger": "0.0209"
    },    
    {
        "Sozialhilfeempfaenger": "0.0222"
    },    
    {
        "Sozialhilfeempfaenger": "0.0235"
    },    
    {
        "Sozialhilfeempfaenger": "0.0254"
    },    
    {
        "Sozialhilfeempfaenger": "0.0031"
    },    
    {
        "Sozialhilfeempfaenger": "0.0032"
    },    
    {
        "Sozialhilfeempfaenger": "0.0036"
    },    
    {
        "Sozialhilfeempfaenger": "0.0038"
    },    
    {
        "Sozialhilfeempfaenger": "0.0037"
    },    
    {
        "Sozialhilfeempfaenger": "0.0037"
    },    
    {
        "Sozialhilfeempfaenger": "0.0039"
    },    
    {
        "Sozialhilfeempfaenger": "0.0039"
    },    
    {
        "Sozialhilfeempfaenger": "0.0042"
    },    
    {
        "Sozialhilfeempfaenger": "0.0044"
    }
]
```

what do i have to do, to store it this way?

```
{
  "sozialhilfeempfaenger": [0.0039, 0.0042...]

}
```

Comment: what have you tried other than fetching the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change it the way you push the array inside the container. Just select the index directly, and push it inside the array.

Idea:

```
$data['sozialhilfeempfaenger'] = array(); // initialize
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data['sozialhilfeempfaenger'][] = $row['Sozialhilfeempfaenger'];
                                      // ^ directly access the index
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "select ((recipients.maennlichDeutsch+recipients.maennlichAuslaender+recipients.weiblichDeutsch+recipients.weiblichAuslaender)/inhab.Einwohner) as Sozialhilfeempfaenger from recipients left join education on recipients.Bundesland = education.FK_Land and recipients.Jahr = education.FK_Jahr left join inhab on recipients.Bundesland = inhab.FK_land and recipients.Jahr = inhab.FK_Jahr where recipients.Bundesland in ('Thueringen') and education.Abschluss in ('Hauptschulabschluss')";
$result=mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');
$data = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $data[] = $row['Sozialhilfeempfaenger'];
}
echo json_encode(array('Sozialhilfeempfaenger' => $data));
?>
```